# XML to XML to HTML using two XSL files

Tags: xml, xslt

Excuse my English in advance, my mother-tongue is French.

I'm currently working on a automatised mail function of a program. 
I must improve an existing function that works like that:
     -the user (a worker of the company I'm intern in) wants to send an email to a client
     -he choose the type of email (example: welcome, deployment, billing)
     -he then gets a form, which is automatically pre-filled with data related to the client retrieved from an SQL database
     -he can, if needed, change some information (add a cc for example), then validate the form
     -the form generates an XML file, which is "linked" to the proper XSL depending on the type of mail. 
     -the XSL file transforms the XML into a HTML file with the final email to be sent to the client.

The problem is that the company is changing the graphic template of the emails. I'm the intern who has to change each and every XSL file to match the new template. I've also been asked to think of a more efficient way to do that.

What i want to do is separate the content and the layout/style (as with a CSS file).

I want a first XSL to turn the form data into a second XML (with all the content), which then gonna be transformed into the final html file using a second XSL file (for the style). Therefore, the second XSL is the only file that gonna need editing in case of a future template change.

**Here is an simplified example.**

Automatically generated XML from the form:

```
<root>
     <typeMail>Prise de contact</typeMail>
     <numCommand>X8374</numCommand>
     <offer>hmm</offer>
     <emailClient>blabla@blabla</emailClient>
     <contactName>toto</contactName>
</root>
```

**Second XML from first transformation:**

```
<email>
   <emailClient>blabla@blabla</emailClient>
   <Header>
      <title> Welcome <title>
      <object> 
         Welcome Mr. <clientData> toto </clientData>. Thanks for subscribing to <commandData>hmm</commandData>
      </object>
   </header>
   <main>
      Your command id is <commandData>X8374</commandData>
   </main>
</email>
```

A second -style- XSL will then turn that second XML into the final HTML file.

My first question is: is that a good solution?
Second question: I've started testing the solution, but can't get the "second xml" to automatically be transformed into the html. I get the second xml. And when i save in and reopen it in the browser now its transformed into the final html. Is there a way for it to be done without the use of any another tool nor code nor script?
That may be a stupid question but it would be great if its possible.

Here are my test files:

**First XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<persons>
   <person username="JS1">
      <name>John</name>
      <family-name>Smith</family-name>
   </person>
   <person username="MI1">
      <name>Morka</name>
      <family-name>Ismincius</family-name>
   </person>
</persons>
```

**First XSL**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/persons">
      <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">type="text/xsl" href="test2.xsl"</xsl:processing-instruction>
      <root>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="person"/>
      </root>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="person">
      <name username="{@username}">
         <xsl:value-of select="name" />
      </name>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Which gives me that**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test2.xsl"?>
<root>
   <name username="JS1">John</name>
   <name username="MI1">Morka</name>
</root>
```

**Second XSL** (a dumb one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
      <head></head>
      <body style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:18pt; color:green">
         blablabla
         <xsl:apply-templates />
         blablabla
      </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
    <p style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:30pt; color:red">
        blibli
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

I know I can in theory just open an html file with a javascript script that will do the transformations but I wish to know if it can be done without that. I guess its just that the intermediate xml file is stored in a temporary folder and doesnt find the path to the second XSL file, but i don't know how to solve the problem...

In case there really is no other way, should i use a script like that? (first ever script. I've put it in the body of an empty html file. tested, not working.. Don't know why..)
Something like that?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   //load xml
   var xml1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
   xml1.async = false 
   xml1.load("xml1.xml")

   //load first xsl
   var xsl1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
   xsl1.async = false 
   xsl1.load("xsl1.xsl")

   //transform first xml
   var xml2 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
   xml2.async = false 
   xml2.write(xml1.transformNode(xsl1))   //not sure of the proper function

   //load second xml
   var xsl2 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
   xsl2.async = false 
   xsl2.load("xsl2.xsl")

   //final html
   document.write(xml2.transformNode(xsl2)) 
</script>
```

Comment: I am not aware of any browser supporting such chaining of XSLT stylesheets based on `xml-stylesheet` pis. So you would need to execute that transformation chain outside of the browser (with any framework or language being able to call an XSLT processor) or within the browser using Javascript.

Comment: Okay, if there is no other way i'm gonna use javascript. But is that a good idea overall to use one xsl for the content and one for the style?
Knowing that I'm just adding a fonctionality to something that already exists and that the ideal is not to change too much stuff